# Problema configurando xdebug en docker para vscode, proyecto en local (xdebug 2.9)

Tags: vscode, docker, xdebug

estoy configurando un docker para poder debugear con xdebug 2.9.

El fichero de configuracion de xdebug : `/etc/php/7.4/mods-available/xdebug.ini` tengo esto :

```
 zend_extension=xdebug.so
 xdebug.remote_enable=1
 xdebug.remote_port=9000
 xdebug.remote_autostart=true
 xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
 xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
 xdebug.remote_mode=req
```

Apache me lo detecta bien :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y mi vscode tiene esta config :

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 0,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
            ],
            "env": {
                "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
                "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
            },
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html/public/test_laravel/public": "${workspaceRoot}/test_laravel/public",
            }
        }
    ] }
```

Mi proyecto en el docker esta bajo ese dir : `/var/www/html/public` . Entonces no se porque no tira el xdebug